# how do i install pyffmpeg on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, cython, pyffmpeg

can anyone point me in the right direction in getting pyffmpeg installed on my windows 10 computer. I seem to be having quite a bit of trouble. is cython required for this? please all input is appreciated.

**update I installed cython and it got stuck on setup.py

it gets stuck installing on line 84

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\setup.py", line 84, in <module>
incdir = incdir + list(nd.get_numpy_include_dirs())
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

the ffmpeg version is ffmpeg-20160415-git-21acc4d-win32-static

I did change the filepath for it as well

Comment: What did you try and what is the problem?

Comment: @ Selcuk i just put an update

Comment: You must post the full traceback of the error. "It gets stuck" is not a hint for debugging.

Comment: @Seluck just got it up

Comment: What is your ffmpeg version? It does not work with newer versions of ffmpeg: https://github.com/mhaller/pyffmpeg/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in *setup.py*

```
    incdir = path_join(ffmpegpath, 'include')
```

is not ok since `incdir` needs to be an array here:

```
if (with_numpy):
    incdir = incdir + list(nd.get_numpy_include_dirs())
```

So,

```
if sys.platform in [ 'win32', 'win64' ] :
    libs = static_resolver(libs)
    libinc += [ r'/mingw/lib' ] # it seems some people require this
    incdir = [ path_join(ffmpegpath, 'include') ]
else:
    incdir = [ path_join(ffmpegpath, 'include'), "/usr/include" , "./include" ]
```

This probably won't help you much since an old version of ffmpeg is probably needed.